# What if I have currentUser == nil in firebase while reauthenticateWithCredential iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication

Sometimes we get Auth.auth().currentUser as nil (May be when session for that login expires).

My main question is:

1. What is the reason behind currentUser being nil.
2. If the curentUser is nil what if I call the reauthenticateWithCredential method on it?
3. Do reAuthenticate method fills the session again and start providing values in the currentUser?

Below is the code to reAuthenticate user.

```
func authenticateUser()
{
    let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: myEmail, password: myPassword)
        Auth.auth().currentUser?.reauthenticate(with: credential, completion: { (dataResult, error) in
            if(error == nil){
                print("Email login success")
                completionHandler(true)
            }else{
                print("Email login failed - " + error.debugDescription)
                completionHandler(false)
            }
        })
}
```

Any HELP will be Appreciated,
Many Thanks!!
Dinal J

Comment: What are 'completionHandler(true)', 'completionHandler(false)' for?

Comment: @ElTomato
That is nothing but to return the status of login method. If there is no error it will return true to the caller else false.